# Import "google_auth_oauthlib.flow" could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

In `VSCODE` using these specifications:

```
pip 21.3.1 from C:\users\computador\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

I'm using this path for installation:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

[image]

But when I try to add the flow import, it keeps saying could not be resolved, several videos use this model to work and none of them show this failure, what is happening and what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try pip uninstall google-auth-oauthlib and pip uninstall google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib then reinstall it.

Comment: Hi @Tirterra It worked perfectly, so simple and it didn't come to my mind to uninstall and reinstall. Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem, sometimes the answer is so obvious that we can't even see it. Could you please change the status to resolved ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Tirterra Create an answer so I can add the checked to it as a solution, without it I can't close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pip uninstall google-auth-oauthlib` and `pip uninstall google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib` then reinstall it with `pip install google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib`

Answer (score 3):

Directly run `pip install google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib` resolves this problem for me.